# BreadcrumbList problem: "The value provided for item.id must be a valid URL."

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool, breadcrumbs

Until last week everythink works fine, but in structured data testing tool, I received problem in breadcrumb section.

> The value provided for *item.id* must be a valid URL.

[image]

Page URL: https://colorwhistle.com/services/wordpress-web-design-development/

This problem is on every page on my website and I can't find source of this problem. Also I have no idea what cause this problem.

Comment: I was able to resolve it by doing the steps provided at this link here https://handyopinion.com/how-to-resolve-invalid-url-in-field-id-error-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use id as well for BreadcrumbList. Edit your code to add id (this can be your URL)
Example code :

```
"item":  
{ 
    "@id": "https://colorwhistle.com/services/wordpress-web-design-development/",
    "name": "WordPress Development Services" 
}
```

**EDIT -** 
Remove URL all together use @id instead

**EDIT 2 -** 
Implementation guidelines and details 
[Google guidelines for Breadcrumb](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb)
[Schema.org for BreadcrumbList](http://%20schema.org/BreadcrumbList)

Comment: More details on Googles guidelines here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb

Comment: Actually, you don't need the URL in the schema as well.  The URL is in HTML the code on the page, then use the same URL as the id.

Comment: yeah this solved my problem.. changed "url" to "id".

Comment: @RanjeethKA please accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: @TonyMcCreath I think this is the one for BreadcrumbList - https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList

Comment: @AnkDasCo The testing tool also reports on issues based on the Google Guidelines, like needing to use id.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath, Google's guidelines and examples do not have any ID. There is no mention of an ID in their documentation.

Comment: @nilocas Looks like Google dropped the id requirement (and optional image) on the 23rd. As the guideline now states, the item can directly be the URL. The old id based method will still work, it's just more complex.